# Trying to get a variable form a script in public gameobject, error CS1061

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a variable "isOffRoad" from script "WheelHandler" in the object "Wheel1".
I am getting the error:

Assets\Scripts\CarControler.cs(53,13): error CS1061: 'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'WheelHandler' and no accessible extension method 'WheelHandler' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Thanks in advance.

Edit: isOffRoad is public.

```
public GameObject Wheel1;

void Update()
    {
        if(Wheel1.WheelHandler.isOffRoad == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("offroad");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access your component with `GetComponent<>()` method.

In your case that would be `Wheel1.GetComponent<WheelHandler>().isOffRoad`

Also It is not recommended to access component in Update loop. It would be better to cache it in a field.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```cs
if (Wheel1.GetComponent<WheelHandler>().isOffRoad))
{
    // do something..
}
```